# ListItem onPress not working as it should

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, listitem, expo

I'm using React Native and react-native-elements to render a list of options in a side menu, however when I run the project, the `onPress` prop in `ListItem` fails to act as it should. The three console logs seem to iterate automatically with the main content on the screen when run, but when the side menu is opened the list items cannot be pressed and nothing further is logged in the console. Is there something wrong with my onPress function?

```
import { SideMenu, List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class Home extends Component {

state = {
    toggled: false,
  }

  toggleSideMenu () {
  this.setState({
    toggled: !this.state.toggled
  })L

render() {
  const list = [
  {
    name: 'Profile',
    pic: 'assignment-ind',
    //nav: this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { user: this.state.user })
    nav: console.log('pressing Profile!'),
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    pic: 'settings-applications',
    nav: console.log('pressing Settings!'), 
  },
  {
    name: 'Logout',
    //nav: firebase.auth().signOut() // sign user out 
    nav: console.log('pressing Logout!'),
  }

]
  const MenuComponent = (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 10}}>
      <List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>
      {
        list.map((item, i) => (
          <ListItem
            onPress={() => item.nav} 
            leftIcon={{ name: item.pic }}
            key={i}
            title={item.name} 

          />
        ))
      }
      </List>
    </View>
  );

    return (
      <SideMenu
        menu={MenuComponent}
        toggled={this.state.toggled}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 9}}
            onPress={this.toggleSideMenu.bind(this)}
            underlayColor='transparent'>
            <MaterialIcons
              color='white'
              name='menu'
              size={28}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        </View>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

I made each proper methods within the list object:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Profile',
    pic: 'assignment-ind',
    //nav: this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { user: this.state.user })
    nav: () => { console.log('pressing Profile!'); },
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    pic: 'settings-applications',
    nav: () => { console.log('pressing Settings!'); }, 
  },
  {
    name: 'Logout',
    //nav: firebase.auth().signOut() // sign user out 
    nav: () => { console.log('pressing Logout!'); },
  }
```

Then I added parentheses to the `onPress` function:

```
onPress={() => item.nav()}
```

Answer (score 1):

onPress has to be a method. You need to make nav of the list a method by binding it there itself. For eg.

```
nav : () => {console.log("Logout pressed")}
```

Also you need to call it from onPress.

```
onPress : item.nav() // Note the brackets.
```

Happy coding.